# How to replace the whole argument part of a C function call?

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed, parentheses

I'm writing a bash script that aims to impact all the files in a folder, in order to **replace all calls to a given C function by changing the argument**.
Here is what the current calls look like, and what I want to obtain :

```
myfunc( foo ) ----> myfunc( foo, foo+1 )
```

I use the following find/sed command and it does the job:

```
find . -name "*" -print | xargs sed -i 's/myfunc\([^)]*)\)/myfunc((\1),(\1)+1)/g'
```

But the issue arise when I have to **deal with instructions/arguments that contains parentheses**, like in the following instruction:

```
sqrt( myfunc( (foo+foo)*bar ) );
```

What happens is that the first closing parenthesis (i.e. the one after `foo`) is interpreted as the end of the `myfunc` argument, which it is not...

How can I get a regexp (or any other command) that capture and replace `(foo+foo)*bar`, i.e. exactly the content of the correct level of parentheses, whatever the number of parentheses levels ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed ':a
s/myfunc(\([^(]\)(\([^)]*\))/myfunc(\1²\2³/
ta
s/myfunc(\([^)]*\))/myfunc(\1, (\1) + 1 )/g
y/²³/()/
'
```

- Try this but it will fail (as is) on recursive call ( `myfunc( 1 - myfunc( 2) )` ) on the second myfunc (normaly few use)) but will work  on several myfunc (non inclusive) on the line.
- assume the open and close `()` are on the same line as `myfunc` (sed works line per line by default)
- posix version (`--posix`on GNU sed)
- use of marker `²³` so assume not used in code, if any use other unused char or pre-modify and put it back after.

**explaination**

- replace any peer of `()` after `myfunc(` by respectively `²³`. (using recursive call to replace lower level per lower level). after the last substitution you have something like `myfunc( subfunc2²  subfunc3² arg31, arg32³, arg22³)`
- take the content between `()` where there is no more `( )` (oops, still could have `( )` in string so buggy on that case) inside and replace with `content, content + 1`
- reset any `²³`to repsectively `()`

Remark: a first round to change (temporary modification with back to original at the end of operation)  is needed for any `(` or `)` that are in string inside `myfunc()` [not very hard to do but annoying]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you briefly explain the mechanism of the command?

Comment: voila, added to the post (and found a limitation)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your line will only contain `myfunc( foo )` and there is no more `)` afterwards, you can do a greedy search like this:

```
myfunc\((.*)\)
```

See example: http://regex101.com/r/gD1mN0/1

Comment: will fail on something like `myfunc(1) + myfunc(2)`